# RealityKit – Plane Detection

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

In RealityKit, similiar to ARKit, objects won't show until the camera has detected some sort of flat surface. Once the camera has detected that surface, the objects will show and pin to it.

How do I know (by code) if the camera has detected a flat surface? Actually, I want to highlight the selectable area but I'm not sure if RealityKit actually allows you to do so, I know SceneKit does tho.

Comment: I think ARCoachingOverlay is what you need. There is a good tutorial for that https://medium.com/@maxxfrazer/realitykit-arcoachingoverlayview-80159d140c Check it out

Answer (score 6):

There's a `plane` initialiser (and enumeration case) in RealityKit for this purpose:

```
convenience init(plane alignment: AnchoringComponent.Target.Alignment,
                  classification: AnchoringComponent.Target.Classification, 
                   minimumBounds: SIMD2<Float>) 

/* Where `minimumBounds` is the minimum size of the target plane */
```

It's a counterpart of ARKit's `ARPlaneAnchor` with `extent` property (that's an estimated width and length of the detected plane). But in RealityKit it works a little bit different.

In a real code you may use it this way:

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane([.horizontal, .vertical],
                 classification: [.wall, .table, .floor],
                  minimumBounds: [0.375, 0.375]))

/* Here we create an anchor for detected planes with a minimum area of 37.5 cm2 */

anchor.addChild(semiTranparentPlaneEntity)        // visualising a detected plane
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

Pay attention that `alignment` and `classification` arguments conform to OptionSet protocol.

And you can always find out whether plane anchor has created or not:

```
let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

let anchor = AnchorEntity(.plane(.any, classification: .any, 
                                        minimumBounds: [0.5, 0.5]))
anchor.name = "PlaneAnchor"


let containsOrNot = arView.scene.anchors.contains(where: {
    $0.name == "PlaneAnchor"
})
print(containsOrNot)

print(arView.scene.anchors.count)
print(arView.scene.anchors.first?.anchor?.id)
```

Comment: how about detecting and visualizating continuously?

Comment: Hi @АлександрГрабовский! What do you mean saying `detecting and visualizing continuously`? Explain it, please.

Comment: I mean the extending `semiTranparentPlaneEntity` while you explore more surface. I was looking for behavior like this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/tracking_and_visualizing_planes. I have found that I can track surface geometry changes in `session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor])` function

Comment: Ok, I've got it. I am still thinking of this question. You may publish it as SO question.

Comment: @АлександрГрабовский we can perhaps use `SceneEvents.Update` for detecting continuously?